# SQL-Style name of variables in a stored procedure

Tags: coding-style, mysql, stored-procedures

As seen in the main question. It is not a syntactic problem that I have, or 
some error in the code. I would like to know what is the correct way to name the parameters variables in a stored procedure. Is there documentation on this topic?

I ask this, for example: I have a database containing a table called "orders" and I made a stored procedure where one of the parameters is an "orderNumber", then I made a Query asking for that orderNumber. 
Is it advisable to put the same name to the parameter as the attribute of the table, for readability topics? What would be the correct solution?

```
USE `classicmodels`;

DROP procedure IF EXISTS `delete_order`;

DELIMITER $$

USE `classicmodels`$$

CREATE PROCEDURE `classicmodels`.`delete_order` (in orderNumber int, out qty int)

BEGIN

    select count(orderNumber) into qty 
    from orderDetails
    where orderNumber = orderNumber;

    if (qty > 0) then
      delete from orderDetails 
      where orderNumber = orderNumber;

      delete from orders 
      where orderNumber = orderNumber;

    end if;

END
$$

DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/search?q=stored+procedure+naming+convention

Comment: I find that the prefix *"arg_"* is useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can use same name to parameter as attribute of a table,but it is not a good way.

It might be ambiguous enough in some procedures/functions that they’re problematic too.

you can use following way:

Simplest way to distinguished between your parameter and column (if both name is same) is to add table name in your column name.

```
select count(orderNumber) into qty 
    from orderDetails
    where orders.orderNumber = orderNumber;
```

Even you can also add database prefix like:

```
select count(orderNumber) into qty 
        from orderDetails
        where dbname.orders.orderNumber = orderNumber;
```

Answer (score -1):

Well first off id say a quick google search is your friend here. However, after doing that myself and being given a whole bunch of results, ill try and explain things.

The best naming convention is one that makes it entirely clear to the user what is happening when they execute/read your code/queries. So you may decide to use sp_ as a prefix for stored procedures. As long as its readable you can use it.

In regards to giving a correct solution to what you have above, well let me answer your question with another question. Your stored procedure deletes an order, by first checking the database to see if there are orders present with the specified order number, and if there are those records are removed. If this is correct, then congratulations your naming convention is great. Otherwise just make it more clear.

Comment: It's OK to use an `sp_` prefix, [except when you're using SQL server](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd172115(v=vs.100).aspx), or [when you're using anything else](https://launchbylunch.com/posts/2014/Feb/16/sql-naming-conventions/#prefixes-and-suffixes-are-bad).  Aside from that, though, it's a matter of taste.